filter bot messages in a discord channel
I would like to know what the easiest way to filter through a bot's messages. The bot does not support this on its own.

This is the bot in talking about: https://throneandliberty.gameslantern.com/tl-discord-bot
you can subsribe to the bot by using /eventsubscribe
I want to hide all information abouth dynamic events, how can i do that? Any ideas?

If the /eventsubscribe subscribes you to both in the above screenshot, there wont be anything to do unless you build you own discord bot to split these events into their own channels or threads. If /eventsubscribe expects variables to subscribe to (1 for Field Boss and 1 for dynamic events), use the command /eventsubscribe <name> in 2 different channels or threads to split these.

unfortunetly it is not possible to only subscribe to one of those types. I already asked in the developer's dc, it is not possible. Can't i use a different bot with auto delete/filter for the keywords 'Dynamic Events'? I Tryed to do that with Carl-bot and put this on bad words, but it does not delete anything so far hmmm

90% of bots out there ignore responses from other bots. This is to prevent loops that will never end. This is why creating your own bot to do this or finding one out there that doesnt explicitly ignore discord bots are your options
